# why Increased Height item Contact when hover on it?

Tags: css

why Increased Height item Contact when hover on it? how fix it?

This is My code :

```css
ul {
            padding: 0;
        }

        #nav ul {
            display: none;
        }
        #nav li:hover > ul {
            display: block;
        }
        
        #nav > li {
            float: left;
        }
        
        #nav li {
            list-style: none;
            width: 150px;
            position: relative;
            border: 1px solid red;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            
        }
        
       
        #nav a {
            display: block;
            background-color: #000;
            color: red;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            text-align: center;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 2px solid transparent;

        }

        #nav ul ul {
            position: absolute;
            left: 150px;
            top: 0;
        }
        #nav li:hover > a {

            color: orange;
        }
        
        #nav li:hover > a:after {
            content:'\25B6';
            color: red;
            margin-left: 5px;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #nav > li:hover > a:after {
            content: '\25BE';
            color: red;
            margin-left: 5px;
            padding: 0;
        }
```

```html
 <div id="wrapper">  
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Product 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Product 2</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Model 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Model 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Model 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Product 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Service 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

See This Image :[image: Here]

Comment: Its because of the :after `content` (`#nav > li:hover > a:after`) you are adding on hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you **hover** over the list items - you're adding an arrow to the anchor tag via generated content.

Thant's what's causing the increase in height.

To fix this - just set `position:absolute` on the generated content.

```css
ul {
            padding: 0;
        }

        #nav ul {
            display: none;
        }
        #nav li:hover > ul {
            display: block;
        }
        
        #nav > li {
            float: left;
        }
        
        #nav li {
            list-style: none;
            width: 150px;
            position: relative;
            border: 1px solid red;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            
        }
        
       
        #nav a {
            display: block;
            background-color: #000;
            color: red;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            text-align: center;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 2px solid transparent;

        }

        #nav ul ul {
            position: absolute;
            left: 150px;
            top: 0;
        }
        #nav li:hover > a {

            color: orange;
        }
        
        #nav li:hover > a:after {
            content:'\25B6';
            color: red;
            margin-left: 5px;
            padding: 0;
            position:absolute;
        }
        #nav > li:hover > a:after {
            content: '\25BE';
            color: red;
            margin-left: 5px;
            padding: 0;
        }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">  
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Product 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Product 2</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Model 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Model 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Model 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Product 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Service 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: tanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Because of

```
#nav > li:hover > a:after {
content: '\25BE';
}
```

the height (font size) is to high of this content.

maybe you should try a background-img.

Or position it absolute and the a-tag relative.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the :after `content` attribute (`#nav > li:hover > a:after`) you are adding on hover(the small arrow icon)

To avoid this, applying `line-height: 0` is an efficient way of doing it.

```
    #nav > li:hover > a:after {
        content: '\25BE';
        color: red;
        margin-left: 5px;
        padding: 0;
        line-height: 0; //fix
    }
```

> Also you have this code twice, make sure you remove the redundant one.

Answer (score 0):

It simple line height issue.

```css
ul {
            padding: 0;
        }

        #nav ul {
            display: none;
        }
        #nav li:hover > ul {
            display: block;
        }
        
        #nav > li {
            float: left;
        }
        
        #nav li {
            list-style: none;
            width: 150px;
            position: relative;
            border: 1px solid red;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            
        }
        
       
        #nav a {
            display: block;
            background-color: #000;
            color: red;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            text-align: center;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 2px solid transparent;
            line-height: 20px;
        }

        #nav ul ul {
            position: absolute;
            left: 150px;
            top: 0;
        }
        #nav li:hover > a {

            color: orange;
        }
        
        #nav li:hover > a:after {
            content:'\25B6';
            color: red;
            margin-left: 5px;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #nav > li:hover > a:after {
            content: '\25BE';
            color: red;
            margin-left: 5px;
            padding: 0;
        }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">  
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Product 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Product 2</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Model 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Model 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Model 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Product 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Service 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```